# How to prevent playing an animation more then once - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, queue, jquery-animate

When rapidly pressing a button that triggers a function with animation, we normally get that function called lots of times, and the animation play once after the other.

What do you do if you don't want the function to be triggered while the animation is still playing?

Here's a simple example of a function that tells a kid to jump:

```
$('button').click(jumpKid);

function jumpKid () { 
 $kid
  .animate({'margin-bottom' : '+=' + 100} , 500)
  .animate({'margin-bottom' : '-=' + 100} , 500)
};
```

Rapidly pressing the button will cause the kid to jump lots of times.

I'm looking for a jquery/js solution (instead of using a var such as "isKidJumping")

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:animated` selector, `.is()`

```
$("button").click(jumpKid);

function jumpKid () { 
 if (!$kid.is(":animated")) {
   $kid
   .animate({'margin-bottom' : '+=' + 100} , 500)
   .animate({'margin-bottom' : '-=' + 100} , 500)
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method:

```
$('button').once('click', jumpKid);

function jumpKid() {
    $kid
        .animate({
            'margin-bottom': '+=' + 100
        }, 500)
        .animate({
            'margin-bottom': '-=' + 100
        }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for in it small intervals:

```
setInterval(function() {
   $("button").click(jumpKid);
},100);
```

or simply toggle between a jumped class:

```
$("button").click(function() {
   kid.removeClass("jumped"));
}
if(!kid.hasClass("jumped")) jumpKid();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detach the event listener while the animation is playing, and as a callback on your last .animate() method call, re-attach it:

```
var $button = $('button');
$button.on('click', jumpKid);

function jumpKid () {

 $button.off('click', jumpKid);
 $kid
  .animate({'margin-bottom' : '+=' + 100} , 500)
  .animate({'margin-bottom' : '-=' + 100} , 500, function(){
      // In a callback function for the last .animate() call, we'll re-attach the event listener:
      $button.on('click', jumpKid);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the answers. I also found a solution which is really simple to use and understand:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  if ($kid.queue().length === 0 ){
    jumpKid();
  }
});


function jumpKid () {
    $kid
    .animate({'margin-bottom' : '+=' + 100} , 500)
    .animate({'margin-bottom' : '-=' + 100} , 500)
}
```

$kid.queue() will return an array that stores the object animations, so $kid.queue().length will show us how many animations are stored.

for example: when you use "$kid.animate..." the $kid.queue().length will return 1.

and so, we can use $kid.queue().length to stop the jumpKid function from being triggered! hooray!